# Java ActiveMQ: How to send a message from the client to the server

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I've seen a lot of code and examples on how to send a message from the server/producer to the client, but I'm lost as to how to send a message from the client to the server.  Does it follow the same format?

For example, say my server has 5 topics: A, B, C, D, E. My client is listening to only topic C.
So my server creates a queue and sends messages to subscribers/clients.
My client gets messages that are on topic C. It performs some computation, and I want to send a message back to the publisher (say an int for example).  What are the  required steps?

Do I need to set a destination/topic for the producer to listen to? 
Does my producer automatically listen to all clients (once they connect)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to do a bit of reading around the various communication models available e.g. [this on JMS Models](http://verticalhorizons.in/difference-between-point-to-point-and-publishsubscribe-jms-messaging-models/).

You have started by using Topics, but your statements hint at a One-to-One relationship between sender and receiver.  For this queues may be more appropriate.  Topics are generally for publishing information where the publisher doesn't know (nor care) about the subscribers - and there can be many.

On the other hand Queuing is intended to deliver to a specific target.  With this you can still do "fire-and-forget" (where the sender puts the message out to a queue and doesn't wait for the expected consumer to process it)

Or you can add response handling to that - essentially by adding a "parallel" response queue (where the initial sender will processes the response messages back from the consumer - usually in a different thread).

ActiveMQ and JMS have ["reply-to" functionality](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) - where the sender indicates on send the queue name where it wants to see responses come back to - and the consumer complies with that.  The reply-to queue can be fixed or a temporary one that the sender creates up-front.

All depends on what model you are going for.